# posix disallows alternation in case. is this a typo?

Tags: sh, posix

[POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_05) states:

> The format for the **case** construct is as follows:
>
> ```
> case word in
>     [(] pattern1 ) compound-list ;;
>     [[(] pattern[ | pattern] ... ) compound-list ;;] ...
>     [[(] pattern[ | pattern] ... ) compound-list]
> esac
> ```

This appears to disallow alternation (ie. multiple patterns)
with the first compound-list.

Clearly, this is not how implementations behave.

```
$ for cmd in bash dash 'busybox sh' ksh; do
> $cmd -c 'case a in a|b|c) echo ok ;; *) echo no ; esac'
> done
ok
ok
ok
ok
$
```

Nor how the grammar itself defines it further down on that page:

> ```
> case_clause      : Case WORD linebreak in linebreak case_list    Esac
>                  | Case WORD linebreak in linebreak case_list_ns Esac
>                  | Case WORD linebreak in linebreak              Esac
>                  ;
> case_list_ns     : case_list case_item_ns
>                  |           case_item_ns
>                  ;
> case_list        : case_list case_item
>                  |           case_item
>                  ;
> case_item_ns     :     pattern ')' linebreak
>                  |     pattern ')' compound_list
>                  | '(' pattern ')' linebreak
>                  | '(' pattern ')' compound_list
>                  ;
> case_item        :     pattern ')' linebreak     DSEMI linebreak
>                  |     pattern ')' compound_list DSEMI linebreak
>                  | '(' pattern ')' linebreak     DSEMI linebreak
>                  | '(' pattern ')' compound_list DSEMI linebreak
>                  ;
> pattern          :             WORD         /* Apply rule 4 */
>                  | pattern '|' WORD         /* Do not apply rule 4 */
>                  ;
> ```

Is this a bug in the spec? (In particular the `1` in `pattern1` looks suspiciously like a mistyped `]` - as if part of that line had been lost/corrupted.)

The same definition text appears as far back as the [2004 edition](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_04_05).

Comment: Grammar is below. `pattern1` is not really defined, so it could be `pattern1 = pattern [| pattern ]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's a bug. That line was removed from the standard as a result of [this bug report](https://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1454) filed back in 2021. The issue 8 drafts have the following text instead:

> The format for the **case** construct is as follows:
>
> ```
> case word in
>    [[(] pattern[ | pattern] ... ) compound-list terminator] ...
>    [[(] pattern[ | pattern] ... ) compound-list]
> esac
> ```
>
> Where *terminator* is either **";;"** or **";&"** and is optional for the last *compound-list*.